# Cordova iOS plugins failing to load

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I've been developing a cross platform application which until recently has caused a few headaches. Android release will load the plugins without any issue at all, however, the iOS seems to have drop. I am unaware if it's something to do with the latest release of iOS (8.2) or something which has caused an issue in a most recent cordova update. Hopefully you guys would be able to shed some light on the matter.

I'm using jQuery Mobile, I've found an article while browsing through Stack Overflow that setting changeHash to false will counter act getting the message `Resetting plugins due to page load.` unfortunately it didn't work

```js
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#questions", {changeHash: false});
```

Another article I've found is that they simply tell me to ignore it, but something tells me not to do that.

In summary, all is well on Android, every plugin which I have installed is working without issue. On iOS non of the plugins are loading, and simply typing `window.plugins` should bring back an object of plugins but it's undefined. I've inserted a try catch to find the problem and this is the error which I am getting.

```
getQuestion: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.captureplugin')
```